# One entity having 2 ManyToOne relations to the same other entity

Tags: php, doctrine, relationship, symfony5

I'm working with Symfony5. I have 2 entities with relationships, Character and Wedding.

Each Character can have many Wedding.
Each Wedding is related to 2 different Character.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=CharacterRepository::class)
 */
class Character
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
 */
private $firstName;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
 */
private $lastName;
[...]
```

And Wedding :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=WeddingRepository::class)
 */
class Wedding
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=4, nullable=true)
 */
private $startYear;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=4, nullable=true)
 */
private $endYear;
[...]
}
```

I tried to set 2 different ManyToOne relations in Wedding entity (persona1 and persona2) but persona1 and persona2 had the same inversedBy="weddings", so it's not working.

I tried 2 ManyToMany relations too, but Doctrine didn't like it :

```
 // Character
  /**
  * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Wedding::class, mappedBy="persona1")
  */
private $weddings1;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Wedding::class, mappedBy="persona2")
 */
private $weddings2;
// Wedding

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Character::class, inversedBy="weddings1")
 */
private $persona1;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Character::class, inversedBy="weddings2")
 */
private $persona2;

The mappings App\Entity\Wedding#persona2 and App\Entity\Character#weddings are inconsistent with each other.
```

What is the good relationship, ManyToOne or ManyToMany, since each Wedding is related to 2 Characters ? How to make it works with Doctrine ?

Thanks for all suggestion !

Ash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to have `ManyToMany` relation between `Wedding` and `Character` entities if there is no such specific reason or differentiation between character 1 and character 2

```
class Character
{
    // ...
    
    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Wedding::class, mappedBy="characters")
    */
    private $weddings;
}

class Wedding
{
    // ...
    
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Character::class, inversedBy="weddings")
     */
    private $characters;
}
```

This way you can scale it in future if you have more characters to be assigned to a wedding

If there are any strict actions that need to be performed specific to character 1 or character 2  depends on your needs, then you can use `OneToMany` and `ManyToOne` as

```
class Character
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Wedding::class, mappedBy="characterA")
     */
    private $weddingsA;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Wedding::class, mappedBy="characterB")
     */
    private $weddingsB;
}

class Wedding
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Character::class, inversedBy="weddingsA")
     */
    private $characterA;
    
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Character::class, inversedBy="weddingsB")
     */
    private $characterB;
}
```

Comment: Hello @M Khalid Junaid,
Thanks for your answer. For now, I'm working on a "OneToMany and ManyToOne" option, like your second example, but I'm not very happy with it. I will try the "ManyToMany" solution soon.
There is no differentiation between $characterA and $characterB, and this relationship means only 2 characters.
Thanks again !

Comment: I tried both solutions, and in my case, ManyToOne is the best relationship. There is a lot of work to be done with the forms, but it works as needed ! Thank you for your help !